# Careers table support inconsistent between preview and actual rendering

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs, markdown

I just edited my careers page, and I added a table in markdown.  I know markdown is only partially supported and I kind of expected it not to work, but the preview rendered it exactly like I wanted, so I got excited.  Upon saving, however, my description looks like a tornado hit it.

Simply adding

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Blah</td>
    <td>ZOMG</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td>Bar</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

will show you that they're not working correctly.

1. Are tables supposed to be supported or not?
2. At any rate, shouldn't the preview match the end result?
3. Is there some better way to do tables in markdown that I'm unaware of?

EDIT: Also... I just tried exporting to PDF and it looks correct.

Comment: Tables are not supported.  It should not have rendered in the preview :\

Comment: @DavidFullerton It renders them correctly in the PDF as well... that's nice, but even more confusing. o_O

Answer (score 1):

As David said in the comments, tables are not supported on your CV.